# Duplicate WordPress civicrm rewrite rule?

Tags: wordpress

The weird errors for me just keep on coming.

Now, WordPress 6.1.1, CiviCRM 5.54.1, Remi PHP 7.4 (using php-fpm), also running current version of JetPack as that seems to affect some things as well.

Twice now, any request to a CiviCRM URL would result in a 404 (which was solved a few times already by various other reasons). This time, using the Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin, I was able to see that there was a not-found seemingly duplicate rule for civicrm, which was breaking things. Flushing the rules from that same plugin's Tools page solves the issue. But, as noted, it's come back.

Looking at access logs, I can tell approximately when it happens, but that hasn't led me conclusively to any other possible cause (scheduled task? web request? system update?). There was an error message in the PHP-FPM logs that might be related to a problem with JetPack syncing, but it's not conclusive.

This site's also been the victim of some DoS type web crawling that required me to blacklist an IP address or two with the OS firewall, accessing well known URLs directly, throwing errors and clogging the threads up, so maybe I'm missing the needle in the noisy haystack.

I don't have the exact rewrite rule that was causing the problem, to compare it to the one that's there to make things work. Hopefully I can remember to save that before flushing rules next time. But, has anyone seen this before and more importantly, know what's causing it?

Thanks.

Michael

Comment: I don't think there's enough info to solve this problem - but I've found similar issues when either a) my `.htaccess` file was missing from my webroot, or b) the Permalink cache in WP was out-of-date (which you can solve by going to **Settings > Permalinks** and simply pressing **Save**.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, not necessarily looking for a solution, just wondering if anyone else has seen a situation where the rewrite rules within WordPress got confused / civicrm rule duplicated but broken. Both of those issues you mentioned are what I was alluding to when I mentioned previous 404's were resolved. (Also, add "Apache server config has to allow overrides.")